# Is it possible to force a new template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to have something like the following (psuedo-C++) class.  The basic idea is any new value will be initialized to the last set value.

StickyData.hpp

```
template<typename T>
class StickyData {
  static T s_lastValue;
  T m_value;
  StickyData() { m_value = s_lastValue; } // Initialize to last set value
  T& operator = (T& rhs)  { 
       m_value = s_lastValue = rhs;
  }
}

template<> StickyData<T>::s_lastValue;
```

UseData.cpp

```
typedef int Ford;
typedef int GM;
typedef int Toyota;

StickyData<Ford> aFord;
StickyData<GM> aGM;
StickyData<Toyota> aToyota;

aFord = 10;
aGM = 2
aToyota = 20;

StickyData<Ford> anotherFord; // I want this automatically initialized to 10
```

For this to work, I need unique compilations of StickyData for each of these typedef's.  I actually thought this would work as-is, but it appears when I run this code that I only have 1 static int created for all these different template instantiations.

Can I force a new template compilation somehow for the same underlying value type?

Comment: `int` is `int` is `int` is `Ford` is `GM` is `Toyota`.

Comment: `typedef`s in C++ create type aliases, *not* new types.

Comment: @jrok dammit - I switched from a basic example to the ever-so-slightly-more-complex actual case, just in case anyone had some better idea's on how to implement this.  I didn't finish editing the code though...  I've updated the question for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example code, Fords, GMs and Toyotas are all the same type. You should declare them as actual separate types:

```
struct Toyota {};
struct Ford   {};
struct GM     {};
```

Currently, your code is equilvient to:

```
HoldData<int> aFord;
HoldData<int> aGM;
HoldData<int> aToyota;
```

---

**Here's a full implementation of what I'm suggesting above:**

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Hash, typename Value>
struct StickyData {
        static Value s_lastValue;
        Value m_value;
        StickyData(): m_value(s_lastValue) {}

        StickyData<Hash, Value> & operator=(Value const & rhs) {
                m_value = s_lastValue = rhs;
                return *this;
        }
};

struct GM {};
struct Ford {};
struct Honda {};

template <typename Hash, typename Value> Value StickyData<Hash, Value>::s_lastValue = 0;

int main() {
        StickyData<GM, int> aGM;
        StickyData<Ford, int> aFord;
        StickyData<Honda, double> aHonda;

        aGM = 3;
        aFord = 4;
        aHonda = 7.89;

        std::cout << "aGM:    " << aGM.m_value << "\n";
        std::cout << "aFord:  " << aFord.m_value << "\n";
        std::cout << "aHonda: " << aHonda.m_value << "\n";
        std::cout << "\n";

        StickyData<GM, int> aNewGM;
        std::cout << "aNewGM: " << aGM.m_value << "\n";
}
```

Which will output:

```
aGM:    3
aFord:  4
aHonda: 7.89

aNewGM: 3
```

---

**In response to the comment:** *"... But the compiler does know the difference, for example, if you have typedef'ed argument, you can mark something explicit which will then not accept a type 'int' as an argument ..."*.

I have the following code:

```
typedef int foo;

class C {
    explicit C(int x);
    explicit C(foo x);
};
```

This code fails to compile with the following error:

```
blah.cc:5:11: error: ‘C::C(foo)’ cannot be overloaded
  explicit C(foo x);
           ^
blah.cc:4:11: error: with ‘C::C(int)’
  explicit C(int x);
           ^
```

Comment: Yes, the code is equivalent to that, but its not exactly the same (ie, thats what I would get if I said #define Ford int  - But the compiler does know the difference, for example, if you have typedef'ed argument, you can mark something explicit which will then not accept a type 'int' as an argument.

Comment: which is actually a solidly good idea, I might try that (marking the constructor explicit)

Comment: I've included a counterexample to what I believe you just suggested, and for my own completeness's sake, I've included a fully buildable example of what I was thinking of.